# Thailand to Myanmar, easiest border crossing

Tags: thailand, myanmar

I will be heading back to Myanmar from Southern Thailand to complete some video work.

Which is the easiest border crossing south of Bangkok and Yangon.

I want to go to Myeik and Dawei to take some video and photos similar to what I have submitted to [Moving Postcards Myanmar](http://www.movingpostcards.tv/myanmar_-_burma/)

After Dawei I will head up to Yangon.

Answer (score 1):

This may be out of date since Myanmar is changing so rapidly these days, but as of July 2014 there are only two [border crossings](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Myanmar#By_land) between southern(-ish) Thailand and Myanmar open to foreigners: **Ranong/Kawthaung** at Myanmar's southernmost tip, and **Three Pagodas Pass** north of Kanchanaburi, not really 'south' at all (it's actually a fair bit north of Bangkok) but still further south than the other two.

Now, Ranong/Kawthaung would be the obvious option since it's much closer, but last I checked (and [Wikivoyage agrees](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Myeik)) the road north to Myeik (Mergui) and Dawei is still off-limits to foreigners.  Apparently it's theoretically possible to fly up, but this looks pretty flaky even by Burmese standards, and that's saying something.

So this means going via the Three Pagodas Pass is your only practical land option, despite the [massive detour involved](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Ranong,+Thailand/Dawei,+Republic+of+the+Union+of+Myanmar/@13.7774831,98.8560206,6z/am=t/data=!3m1!4b1!4m16!4m15!1m5!1m1!1s0x305645e5447ac1b1:0x10223bc2c364cd0!2m2!1d98.6084641!2d9.9528702!1m5!1m1!1s0x30e50bc719b6f191:0xa7c45ea8fdf2bb4a!2m2!1d98.2!2d14.083333!2m1!6e4!3e0).  Getting there from Bangkok is fairly straightforward, and there's supposed to be a bus onward to Mawlamyine, from where you can make your way south.  However, even this border crossing is quite new and there are [some reports of visa shenanigans](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-mainland/topics/three-pagodas-pass-payathonzu-sangkhlanburi-border-crossing), so due diligence will be required.

Of course, the sensible, comparatively expensive and arguably boring option would be to ditch the land crossings entirely and fly in via Bangkok and Yangon.

Comment: Thanks So maybe it's back again to Yangon but this time head as far south as we can

Answer (score 1):

I believe Mae Sot / Myawaddy is south of YGN, though not of BKK.   As of early this year it was easy and well served (by bus on both sides).   It is fairly close to Mawlamyaing.

Make sure you have your visa together for entering back into Thailand, if that's your plan.  Oddly enough, that might be the stricter direction, these days.

Comment: I used the Mae Sot/Myawaddy crossing in March 2016 and it was very easy. There is a new road on the Myanmar side which makes access to Myawaddy much easier.